# Палиндром при удалении символов

Tags: javascript

Линейный тип данных называется палиндромом, если он читается одинаково справа налево, например, слово «babab».
Написать код который считает минимальное количество символов,при удалении которых строка становится палиндромом

**Поможете решить задачу?получается она сложная походу для всех нас ))**

```js
function solution(x){
    var pat = 0
    if (x === x.split("").reverse().join("")) {return pat}
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (var j = x.length-1; j > i; j--) {
            if (x[i]==x[j]) {
                pat = i + x.length-1 - j
                x = x.substring(i+1,j)
                if (x === x.split("").reverse().join("")) {return pat}
            }
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (var j = x.length-1; j > i; j--) {
            if (x[i]==x[j]) {
                pat = i + x.length-1 - j
                x = x.substring(i+1,j)
                if (x === x.split("").reverse().join("")) {return pat}
            } else {
                pat++
                x = x.slice(1)
            }
        }
    }
    if (x.length==1 || x.length==0 || x.length==2) {
        return pat
    }
}

console.log(solution("wanna")) //1
console.log(solution("anna")) //0
console.log(solution("qaxaqax")) //2
console.log(solution("aebcbda")) //2
```

> **Она не идеальная,а если например там не 2 а 3 элементы? )) не написать же 3 цикла**

Comment: рекурсия *(7 символов нужно...)*

Comment: что дальше?что поменять?

Comment: Поменять код, сделав вызовы функции `solution` рекурсивными, и передавать туда в цикле текущую строку без одной буквы, пока не получится палиндром или не останется одна буква (это считается палиндромом?).

Comment: ну одна буква считается палиндромом
подумать надо как решить

Comment: "подумать надо как решить" - +1

Comment: смотри этот вариант не сработает для например 20 символов )) цикл будет работать 10000000 раз ))) 
может быть вариант получше найдем?

Comment: Что значит "не сработает"? Откуда взялось число 10000000? Может быть найдете.

Comment: смотри берет первый,удаляет проверят и так с каждым,если нет берет первый и какой то из оставшихся если нет то берет первый,второй и какой то другой,и так пока не останется 1 элемент либо не будет палиндрома
правильно я понял твое решение?

Comment: Да. *(11 символов нужно...)*

Comment: ты имеешь ввиду твой код состоит из 11 символов и решил задачу???

Comment: Нет. Комментарий "Да." на одиннадцать символов короче, чем минимальный допустимый комментарий.

Comment: ааа а я думаю че ты там в скобках уже второй раз пишешь ))))

Comment: с кодом поможешь?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109536/discussion-between-robb-stark-and-igor).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Решил с помощью @Lexx918**

```js
function solution(str){
    var n = str.length
    var L = []
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        let tox = []
        L.push(tox)
        L[i][i] = 1
    }
    for (let cl = 2; cl <= n; cl++){
        for ( let i = 0;i < n - cl + 1;i++){
            var j = i + cl - 1
            if (str[i] == str[j] && cl == 2){
                L[i][j] = 2
            }
            else if (str[i] == str[j]){
                L[i][j] = L[i + 1][j - 1] + 2
            }
            else{
                L[i][j] = Math.max(L[i][j - 1],L[i + 1][j])
            }
        }
    }
    return n - L[0][n - 1]
}

console.log(solution("wanna"),"wanna") //1
console.log(solution("anna"),"anna") //0
console.log(solution("qaxaqax"),"qaxaqax") //2
console.log(solution("aebcbda"),"aebcbda") //2
console.log(solution("abcdeak"),"abcdeak") //4
console.log(solution("abcdfedcba"),"abcdfedcba") //1
console.log(solution("abcdedcba"),"abcdedcba") //0
console.log(solution("aeccbda"),"aeccbda") //3
console.log(solution("abbca"),"abbca") //1
console.log(solution("wa"),"wa") //1
console.log(solution("badba"),"badba") //2
console.log(solution(" "),"") //0
console.log(solution("010000"),"010000") //1
console.log(solution("010100"),"010100") //1
console.log(solution("011100"),"011100") //1
console.log(solution("010140"),"010140") //1
console.log(solution("015140"),"015140") //1
console.log(solution("011100011000"),"011100011000") //3
console.log(solution("bbaaaba"),"bbaaaba") //2
```

Comment: Т.е. что я вчера написал - можно было не читать и не вдаваться ;)

Answer (score 0):

Заранее один раз проверяем, не является ли строка палиндромом. Если так, то ничего делать не надо и сразу возвращаем лучший вариант - 0 замен.

Иначе начинаем увеличивать число замен и проверять каждый вариант отдельно. С единицы до длины строки минус 2 т.к. "длина строки минус 1" - это просто удаление всех символов кроме одного и такой вариант мы вернём в самом конце как единственно возможный.

Для каждой итерации находим все возможные комбинации индексов в строке, которые можно удалить и получить таким образом уникальные строки поменьше.

Перебираем эти варианты индексов. Для каждой пачки перебираем сами индексы. Удаляем символы из строки по ним (обязательно с конца к началу, чтобы индексы в конце строки "не поехали"). Затем проверяем результат и принимаем решение.

```js
function solution(S) {
  const isPoly = s => s.join("") === s.reverse().join("");

  const idx = (from, to, size) => {
    let res = [];
    if (size) {
      for (let i = from; i <= to - (size - 1); i++) {
        let el = [i];
        if (size > 1) {
          let additional = idx(i + 1, to, size - 1);
          for (let a = 0; a < additional.length; a++) {
            res.push(el.concat(additional[a]));
          }
        } else {
          res.push(el);
        }
      }
    }
    return res;
  };
  
  if (isPoly(S.split(""))) {
    return 0;
  }

  for (let rm = 1; rm < S.length - 1; rm++) {
    let rmIdx = idx(0, S.length - 1, rm);
    for (let a = 0; a < rmIdx.length; a++) {
      let A = rmIdx[a];
      let s = S.split("");
      for (let i = A.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        s.splice(A[i], 1);
        if (isPoly(s)) {
            return rm;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return S.length - 1;
}

console.log("wanna -> _anna (1): " + solution("wanna"));
console.log("anna -> anna (0): " + solution("anna"));
console.log("qaxaqax -> qaxaq__ (2): " + solution("qaxaqax"));
console.log("aebcbda -> a_bcb_a (2): " + solution("aebcbda"));
console.log("abcdfedcba -> abcd_edcba (1): " + solution("abcdfedcba"));
```

Итого:

```
wanna -> _anna (1): 1
anna -> anna (0): 0
qaxaqax -> qaxaq__ (2): 2
aebcbda -> a_bcb_a (2): 2
abcdfedcba -> abcd_edcba (1): 1
```

Comment: А сработает на abcdfedcba ?

Comment: Неправильно. Символы могут удаляться из середины. `aebcbda` - 2 (`e` и `d`)

Comment: Мне показалось условие - удалять с краёв. Можно и из центра. Секунду..

Comment: @Lexx918 вариант был хорошим,я с начала тож думал что можно убирая с краев получить ответ,но нет.
Вариантов тут много но ни одна не идет к ответу

Comment: Поправил решение, теперь оно общее и удаляет символы из любой части строки. Старое частное решение осталось в истории изменений. Не смог совсем обойтись без рекурсии, но если ещё чуток подумать, то наверняка можно избавиться и от неё.

Comment: @ROBBSTARK если надо обязательно без рекурсии, то надо ещё времени. Иначе думаю такое решение норм.

Comment: Спасибо тебя конечно,но все таки решение не всегда правильна,конечно я не знаю на каких примерах не правильна,но программа которая проверят твой код выдает что не всегда правильна )))

Comment: скорее всего не влезает в ограничения по ресурсам. попробуйте реализовать готовые алгоритмы. благо они есть в сети: http://espressocode.top/minimum-number-deletions-make-string-palindrome/ или http://espressocode.top/minimum-number-deletions-make-string-palindrome-set-2/

Answer (score 0):

Эту задачу можно решить с помощью динамического программирования.
Заводится таблица `NxN` (`N=len(s)`), в ячейках `A[l,r]` которой будут содержаться наибольшие длины палиндромных подпоследовательностей подстроки, начинающейся в позиции `l` и кончающейся в позиции `r`.

Понятно, что диагональ заполняется единицами (односимвольная подстрока есть палиндром).

Потом проверяем:

если `r-l=1`, то `A[l,r] = 1 или 2` в зависимости от равенства символов

если `s[l]` не равно `s[r]`, то `A[l,r]` есть максимум из результатов для укороченных слева и справа подстрок

```
 A[l, r] = max(A[l+1,r], A[l, r-1])
```

а если равно, то к выбору добавляется ещё один член, т.к. совпадающие символы справа и слева образуют палиндром с любым внутренним палиндромом

```
 A[l, r] = max(A[l+1,r], A[l, r-1], A[l+1,r-1]+2)
```

Comment: такое ощущение что тут про поиск максимального палиндрома в строке, а не про то, как его найти удалив каике-либо символы из строки.

Comment: @teran Не-не, тут как раз можно пропускать ненужные символы, а в обычной задаче про поиск максимального палиндрома он должен быть непрерывным. Т.е. составили палиндромчик из середины строки, а потом можно его нарастить не соседними символами.

Comment: @MBo может с кодом поможешь? увидим

Comment: Нет, код писать не буду, на JS я прилично не сделаю. Описание принципа важнее, тем более, что оно подробное и без намёков.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение с помощью рекурсии)

```js
function solution(input){
    function rec(a, b){
        if(a >= b) 
            return 0;

        if(input[a] == input[b])
            return rec(a + 1, b - 1);

        return Math.min(rec(a + 1, b), rec(a, b - 1)) + 1;
    }

    return rec(0, input.length - 1);
}

console.log(solution("wanna"),"wanna") //1
console.log(solution("anna"),"anna") //0
console.log(solution("qaxaqax"),"qaxaqax") //2
console.log(solution("aebcbda"),"aebcbda") //2
console.log(solution("abcdeak"),"abcdeak") //4
console.log(solution("abcdfedcba"),"abcdfedcba") //1
console.log(solution("abcdedcba"),"abcdedcba") //0
console.log(solution("aeccbda"),"aeccbda") //3
console.log(solution("abbca"),"abbca") //1
console.log(solution("wa"),"wa") //1
console.log(solution("badba"),"badba") //2
console.log(solution(" "),"") //0
console.log(solution("010000"),"010000") //1
console.log(solution("010100"),"010100") //1
console.log(solution("011100"),"011100") //1
console.log(solution("010140"),"010140") //1
console.log(solution("015140"),"015140") //1
console.log(solution("011100011000"),"011100011000") //3
console.log(solution("bbaaaba"),"bbaaaba") //2
```